# Is it possible to return an unencoded/unescaped/raw string from a MVC 3 Razor HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created an `HtmlHelper` Extension method which returns an encoded string, I have tried returning `IHtmlString` and `MvcHtmlString` but cannot get the string unencoded/unescaped?

I am trying to reduce the code, so I dont need `Html.Raw()` in this particular instance.

**UPDATE**

This is an interesting one. I am new to Razor, so added the Method I wanted to a `WebViewPage` base class, which obviously didnt work, then created the Method in an HtmlHelperExtension class.

In the view I had `@MyMethod()` which was working and rendering the un-encoded html.

I only noticed that I had ommited the "`Html.`" bit after seeing Darin Dimitrov's answer, so have added the `Html.` and removed the method from the `WebViewPage` class, which fixes the existing HtmlHelper I had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) should do the job:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Foo(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>");
    }
}
```

and in your razor view:

```
@Html.Foo()
```

would produce in the resulting html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

which is unencoded.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this, but your answer helped me spot something, please see my updated question.

Comment: @Mark Redman, OK, so, is my answer acceptable or you still have other issues?

Comment: Yes, accepted, was just wondering if anyone had any comment before I "closed" it...